# How can I save the state of open windows when I reboot?

Tags: pantheon, session

On macOS the locations of windows, running apps, and current working directory for each tab of Terminal (not to mention the terminal size and colors) is saved and restored across reboots. It looks like GNOME supports some of this behavior. How can I do this with Pantheon in elementary OS?

Is window name and location stored in a file somewhere which could be used to restore later?

Answer (score 1):

Pantheon will remember the last size, monitor (for multiple monitor set ups) and location that application windows were closed on/at. So if you close each application in the location you want it prior to rebooting when you reopen the applications they should be in the same location. This does not happen if you reboot without first closing the windows.

I tried setting org/gnome/gnome-session/auto-save-session with dconf editor but did not have any luck.

I do enjoy this feature in mac OS however I have found the above behavior to be adequate for my needs.

I am interested to see if anyone else can provide a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with [lwsm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/linux-window-session-manager). It will save the current window session state after issuing `lwsm save`.

You will have to install node for that:
`sudo apt-get install nodejs`
...next install it with `npm install linux-window-session-manager`.

Open up your windows and save them with `lwsm save`.
Then you just need to make sure you load it on startup.
Go to: System settings -> Applications -> Startup tab
and choose Add -> Custom command and type `lwsm restore`.

Reboot and voila :)

Comment: Unfortunately, this solution is not working, it throws a lot of errors.

Comment: Can you please elaborate which kind of errors and OS version you are using?

Comment: @aranko I am using Elementary OS Hera 5.1.7